# Random numbers only initialize once

Tags: java

I am trying to give each index of each object "Room" in the 2d array maze a random value between 0 and 9. However, during the for loop where I create each unique room's numbers, it instead gives all rooms the numbers generated for the last room. I am completely stumped.

I have tried allocating the randomization to a new method, and directly changing the indices using "maze[i][j].structure[1][2]" to no avail.

```
public class Room { 
    static int[][] structure;
    boolean exists;

    // Constructor Declaration of Class 
    public Room(int[][] structure, boolean exists) 
    { 
        this.structure = structure;
        this.exists = exists;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Room[][] maze = new Room[3][3];
        // setup array of rooms
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
                int a = (int)(Math.random()*9);
                int b = (int)(Math.random()*9);
                int c = (int)(Math.random()*9);
                Out.println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
                int[][] roomBuild = {{1,1,1,1,1},
                                     {1,a,b,c,1},
                                     {1,1,1,1,1}};
                maze[i][j] = new Room(roomBuild, true);
                //int[] nums = Logic.genRoom();
                //maze[i][2].structure[1][1] = nums[0];
                //maze[i][2].structure[1][2] = nums[1];
                //maze[i][2].structure[1][3] = nums[2];
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
                for (int k=0; k<3; k++) {
                    for (int l=0; l<5; l++) {
                        System.out.print(maze[i][j].structure[k][l]);
                    }
                    Out.println();
                }   
                Out.println(i + "," + j + ", " + maze[i][j].exists);
                Out.println();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why don't use [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `structure` as `static`–this means there is only one, and you keep overwriting it.

Declare it like your `exists` variable, e.g., not static.